# Why is this not animating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-plot, pie-chart

I implemented [corePlot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) in my `xcode` project. I have a pie chart that I'm trying to animate. Here is my code:

```
- (void)configureChart
{
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;

    CPTPieChart *pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
    pieChart.dataSource = self;
    pieChart.delegate = self;
    pieChart.pieRadius = (self.hostView.bounds.size.height * 0.7) / 2;
    pieChart.startAngle = M_PI_4;
    pieChart.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionClockwise;

    [graph addPlot:pieChart];
```

This is what  I tried:

```
    CABasicAnimation *rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    rotation.duration = 1.0f;
    rotation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    rotation.delegate = self;
    [pieChart addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"rotation"];
}
```

When I run the app, it doesn't animate. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

**Update 1**

I tried the following:

```
[CPTAnimation animate:pieChart property:@"startAngle" from:pieChart.startAngle to:pieChart.endAngle duration:1.0];
```

That didn't have the desired effect. The chart would show for a second, then disappear.

**Update 2**

I'm trying to get this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/ozgr1wfx/

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you not need to give the animation a `toValue`? Values should be in radians. Use `DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(<value in degrees>)`.

Comment: Do you mean this `#define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))`

Comment: `#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees) (M_PI * (degrees) / 180.0)`

Comment: From your demo link, rotating the image seems wrong. @EricSkroch 's answer below makes more sense. Use the animation that comes with the corePlot classes to animate the appropriate property.

Comment: You seem to know about corePlot. Can you please show me an example? I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Not really. I just looked at the source and Eric's answer. You seem to want to draw a pie chart with a given size of pie segment and to animate to the final size from 0. The tool looks like it lets you animate things like the value from a start value to a final value.

Comment: But what should the property value be?

Comment: I would say animate end angle from start angle to start angle + PI*2. https://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/group__plot_animation_pie_chart.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it thanks to @RoryMcKinnel.

```
[CPTAnimation animate:pieChart property:@"endAngle" from:pieChart.startAngle + M_PI * 2 to:pieChart.startAngle  duration:2.0];
```

This will animate your pie chart like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ozgr1wfx/.

Again. Thanks to @RoryMcKinnel who put me on the right track to get it!

Answer (score 0):

Don't animate the layer transform. Animate the start angle instead. Otherwise, any labels and other annotations will rotate with the plot.

From the *Plot Gallery* example app:

```
[CPTAnimation animate:piePlot
             property:@"startAngle"
                 from:CPTFloat(M_PI_2)
                   to:CPTFloat(M_PI_4)
             duration:0.25];
```

As noted in the comments, angles are given in radians (pi radians = 180 degrees).

Comment: How can I get it to not show anything then animate clockwise on the screen?

Comment: What do you mean "not show anything"? You can animate both the `startAngle` and `endAngle` to grow the graph as shown in the example app or use Core Animation (CA) to fade in the whole plot if you want. You can also use CA to animate the angles since they're just `CGFloat` values.

Comment: Animate the `endAngle`. Have the animation start at the `startAngle`.